# Segmentation fault after function call in x86 assembly

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm currently writing a compiler and I have created some tests and only one of them fails with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` as error message.

This is the code that gets compiled

```
function main(): int {
    var f: int = 10;
    return func(f) - func(f / 2);
}

function func(a: int): int {
    return a;
}
```

And this is the generated assembly code (it's not really optimized as you can see)

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    call function_main
    mov rdi, rax
    mov rax, 60
    syscall

global function_main
function_main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 4
    mov rax, 10
    mov DWORD[rbp-0], eax
    mov eax, DWORD[rbp-0]
    mov rdi, rax
    call function_func
    push rax
    mov eax, DWORD[rbp-0]
    mov rbx, 2
    idiv rbx
    mov rdi, rax
    call function_func
    mov rbx, rax
    pop rax
    sub rax, rbx
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret

global function_func
function_func:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 4
    mov DWORD[rbp-0], edi
    mov eax, DWORD[rbp-0]
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

The assembly file is compiled with `nasm -f elf64 ./test9.lv.asm -o ./test9.lv.asm.o` and `ld -g ./test9.lv.asm.o a.out`

I've used `gdb` to debug the binary file and it seems like the program receives the SIGSEGV signal right after `func(f)` returns the first time.

But now I don't know why this is happening in this case.

Comment: Don't know the answer but accessing `[rbp - 0]` (which is just the same as `[rbp + 0]`) is almost certainly not what you want. The old `rbp` value (pushed by `push rbp`) lives in that stack slot. This should only cause a segmentation fault on the `mov rsp, rbp` of `function_main` though.

Comment: Your `function_func` overwrites the saved RBP value that it's going to restore, so that's not a good start.  I guess that it's not segfaulting *right* after, but actually at `mov eax, DWORD[rbp-0]` in the caller.

Comment: Did you start with `gcc -O0` asm and copy some of its inefficiencies on purpose?  Is that why you're reloading into EAX and then doing `mov rdi, rax`?  Instead of just loading into EDI in the first place.

Comment: @ecm so I should start at `[rbp - 8]` to avoid overwriting the old `rbp` value and `[ebp - 4]` to avoid overwriting the old `ebp`?

Comment: @PeterCordes that is what my compiler generates. It's my first compiler and that's currently the easiest way to get it done :) and yes your right, the segfault should be at `mov eax, DWORD[rbp-0]`

Comment: Ok, then your compiler is broken because it doesn't know that the 8 bytes from [rbp + 0..7] are already in use holding the data stored by `push rbp`.  Use a debugger to look at register values as you single step, especially the ones used in the addressing mode at the segfault.

Comment: I'm now adding 8 bytes to all addresses and now it's working. Thank you for helping :)